# I need to remove useless polygons from my model

Tags: modeling

I have to remove those lines on the sides, so it would look cleaner

From this :
[image: Lada 2107]

To this :
[image: Lada 2107 clean]

But i don't want to use the dissolve edges thing because it will do this :
[image: It doesnt show the yellow line]

It doesn't show the yellow line, and the thing is that i need to see that. It cuts as normal but it doesn't shows.
[image: Cuts normal.]

Comment: Loop cuts don't work on faces which are ngons which is what yours would be if you removed those edges. They aren't going to show in rendered view, so why delete them?

Comment: The loop cut tool only goes through quads. So dissolving is not  an option as it creates n-gons. Have you tried to use the knife tool to cut through the mesh after dissolving? Coz then it will leave you with four quads in the bottom

Answer (score 1):

The Loop cut tool only works on Face loops (rows of quads). That face on the car has more than 4 sides so it won't work on it.

[image]

The reason it looks like it's working is because the loop is cutting all the way through the back and since there is only 1 face between the ends it connects them as well. If you dissolve the other side it won't work at all

You can either keep the faces like that to use the loop cut tool and then add a Decimate modifier to the object so that it merges them after you are done maipulating the geometry.

Or you can use the knife tool (K) to cut the lines from the front to the back. It can be restricted to an axis and can cut through the model as well. The keys are in the bottom tool tips when you activate it.
You can also just select those 2 edges and hit W->Subdivide.
[image]
It will create a vertex in the middle of them and connect them

Comment: Thanks, but this is chinese for me. I am only a starter.

Comment: @Mark You need to get at least basics to be able to comprehend possible answers. Start with some beginner tutorials maybe. There are plenty on YouTube.

Comment: Loop cut tool is the Ctrl+R yellow line. Quads are square faces with 4 sides. I suggest you look up a youtube tutorial on the Knife tool. It's pretty useful but it does have few settings that are hard to explain here